# Python скриптовый язык?

Tags: python

Учительница по информатике сказала, что он скриптовый. Так ли это? Он же вроде компилируемый.
Мне 15, я не Senior разработчик, поэтому вопрос глупый. Я ведь даже на Python не пишу.

Comment: Вообще неплохо бы сначала узнать что учительница понимает под словом «скриптовый» и какие есть ещё варианты

Comment: Разница между программами и скриптами довольно размыта. Нет чёткого определения скриптового языка. `Python` - язык общего назначения. Его частично можно отнести к скриптовым, но этим он не ограничивается.

Comment: Да сейчас чуть ли не все скриптовые языки компилируются.

Comment: @anshap, откуда вы знаете контекст утверждения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Под словом "скриптовый" чаще всего понимается понятие, близкое к "сценарию", то есть имеется в виду, что программа выполняется построчно сверху вниз. В IT-среде, как правило, произнося фразу "Я там небольшой скриптик написал для...", разработчик имеет в виду именно некий "сценарий" для автоматизации чего-либо. Питон для этой цели более чем подходит. Поэтому если тебя интересует просто ответ "да" или "нет", без досужих рассуждений, то да, скриптовый.

P.S. Для ценителей - "скриптовый" == "интерпретируемый" НО в то же время "скриптовый" !== "интерпретируемый" :) если вы понимаете о чём я

Answer (score 9):

**Python - интерпретируемый язык программирования.**
Исходный код выполняется непосредственно, команда за командой (иногда — с минимальной подготовкой, буквально после разбора исходного кода в AST),— программа просто не может быть запущена без наличия интерпретатора.

В случае с самой распространенной реализацией (CPython: написанный на C, часто называемый просто “Python") ответ: интерпретируемый, с некоторой компиляцией. CPython компилирует исходный код на Питоне в байт код, а затем интерпретирует этот байткод, запуская его в процессе.

Частично взято и дополнено [отсюда](https://habr.com/ru/post/209812/)

Так же [согласно](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/blurb/)

> Python - это интерпретируемый объектно-ориентированный язык
>   программирования высокого уровня...

Comment: Однако CPython компилируется. Кстати, а разве скриптовый = интерпретируемый?

Comment: CPython является исключительно интерпретатором байт-кода. А вот код написанный на Сython - действительно, сначала преобразуется в код на С++, а затем компилируется. Но это совершенно разные  инструменты.

Answer (score 5):

Скорей всего учитель разделила языки на системные и сценарные. Первые чаще всего компилируются, вторые - интерпретируются.
Среди сценарных можно выделить: командные языки - `bash`, `powershell`, прикладные - `VBA`, `1С` (омг) и так называемые общего назначения/универсальные - `python`, `javascript`, `perl`, `php`, `ruby`.
Если язык интерпретируемый, то при его запуске осуществляется мнговенное выполнение команд (строк) из вашего сценария. Порядок таков:

- прочитать инструкцию;
- проанализировать инструкцию и определить соответствующие действия;
- выполнить соответствующие действия;
- если не достигнуто условие завершения программы, прочитать следующую инструкцию и перейти к пункту 2.

Такая реализация имеет и плюсы и минусы. Плюсы очень сильны, поэтому эти языки очень популярны.

Answer (score 2):

Это понятие относительное.Питон насколько я знаю конвертируется в байт код (.pyc ) ,а потом исполняется.
Википедия:

> > Python — высокоуровневый язык программирования общего назначения...

Это вопрос "питон компилируется или интерпретируется или одновременно и то  и то":

"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889747/is-python-interpreted-or-compiled-or-both"

Is python a scripting language?

https://www.educba.com/python-scripting-language/

https://www.quora.com/Is-Python-a-programming-language-or-scripting-language

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386442/python-is-language-or-script-language

Wikipedia:

> > Python is an **interpreted**, high-level, general-purpose programming language. Created by Guido van Rossum and first released in 1991, Python's design philosophy emphasizes code readability with its notable use of significant whitespace. Its language constructs and object-oriented approach aim to help programmers write clear, logical code for small and large-scale projects.